# Wrong actions showing up on highlights panel

Tags: page-layout, highlights-panel

I have an opportunity page layout with a bunch of actions on it.  I've assigned it to a specific record type and profile (Agent).  It shows up fine for a user in that profile.

I now cloned the profile (Agent v2).  The new profile has the same page layout assignments as the old one.  However, when viewing in lightning, the highlights panel shows actions that do NOT coincide at all with what's on the page layout.  The actual page layout (fields and field order) is correct.

Has anyone experienced this before?  I tried re-saving the layout, as well as assigning a different page layout.  The actions in the highlight panel just never change.  The weird thing is, the actions in the highlight panel do not coincide with ANY opp page layout I currently have

Comment: One thing I could think is caching. Have you turned off caching in session settings?

Comment: I haven't, but I switched over these users a day ago and the issue hasn't fixed itself.